# how to remove duplicate and filter array object like below mentioned

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

let array1 = [{id: 562, name: "Eva Bridal"},{id: 582, name: "Finger Touch"},]

let array2 = [{id: 575, name: "Saloon Grand"} , {id: 562, name: "Eva Bridal"}]

Final Output :

```
let newarray = [{id: 582, name: "Finger Touch"},{id: 575, name: "Saloon Grand"} ]
```

Comment: so if there are duplicates, both should be removed ?

Comment: Please show what you have tried. Stackoverflow is not a free code writing service. The objective is for you to show your code attempts and people help you resolve bugs in **your code**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add all items from `array1`, and those items from `array2` that are not found in `array1` to a resulting array.

This uses spread syntax in an array literal, and `.filter()` with `.find()` to exclude the duplicates.

```js
let array1 = [{id: 562, name: "Eva Bridal"},{id: 582, name: "Finger Touch"},];

let array2 = [{id: 575, name: "Saloon Grand"} , {id: 562, name: "Eva Bridal"}];

var result = [
  ...array1.filter(o => !array2.find(o2 => o.id == o2.id)),
  ...array2.filter(o => !array1.find(o2 => o.id == o2.id))
];

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Doesn't produce expected results

Comment: You're right. So OP wants both dupes  to be removed. I'll update it.

Comment: Hi everything okay how to get the only array 2 items  end result like this [
  
  {
    "id": 575,
    "name": "Saloon Grand"
  }
]

Answer (score 0):

I assume that a duplicate can appear more than once (ie 3 items with the same id). If this is the case, you can use a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to hold existing ids. [Concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) the two arrays, and use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=a) to create a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map). If an item's `id` exists in the Set, remove it from Map, if not add the item to the Map, and it's `id` to the Set. When the reduce process ends, get the [Map values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/values), and [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) to an array:

```js
const array1 = [{id: 562, name: "Eva Bridal"},{id: 582, name: "Finger Touch"}]

const array2 = [{id: 575, name: "Saloon Grand"}, {id: 562, name: "Eva Bridal"}]

const existing = new Set();
const result = [...array1.concat(array2).reduce((r, o) => {
  if(existing.has(o.id)) {
    r.delete(o.id);
  } else {
    existing.add(o.id);
    r.set(o.id, o);
  }

  return r;
}, new Map).values()];

console.log(result);
```

If you are sure that there will only be pairs of duplicated items (ie - no more than 2 items with the same `id`), use just the Map, and remove an item if it already exists in the Map:

```js
const array1 = [{id: 562, name: "Eva Bridal"},{id: 582, name: "Finger Touch"}]

const array2 = [{id: 575, name: "Saloon Grand"}, {id: 562, name: "Eva Bridal"}]

const result = [...array1.concat(array2).reduce((r, o) => {
  if(r.has(o.id)) {
    r.delete(o.id);
  } else {
    r.set(o.id, o);
  }

  return r;
}, new Map).values()];

console.log(result);
```